# Capistrano deployment detected as shellshock

Tags: capistrano

We upgraded firewall firmware on servers, and the firmware update contains shellshock protection.

Suddenly whenever we do deploy with Capistrano the firewall block our office so we get "Blocked because of IPS attack" from firewall.

I bundle update Capistrano and all dependencies to latest version and same result. Anyone had and know fix for this issue ?

my versions

- capistrano (3.2.1 8290d3f)
- capistrano-bundler (1.1.3)
- capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
- capistrano-rbenv (2.0.2)

Comment: I'm guessing it have something to do with capistrano executing multiple commands as a separate ssh commands (multiple ssh triggers from same IP). I'm going to use Mina (execute multiple commands as a part of one ssh command) and see if that will help https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/faster-web-application-deployments-using-mina-instead-of-capistrano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me being too stupid. Few weeks ago I installed extension to my browser for specifying custom headers. I created some custom malicious headers and was trying to crack my page to see what will happen. Of course I forget to turn it of.

each time I was doing deployment I checked it with the web-browser (with faulty extension) therefore locking my access and blaming it on deployment.

more info here https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1176#issuecomment-62020915